# i want to insert post in specific category using wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress, insert, categories, posts

i used wp_insert_post to add posts to custom post type i had created but i need to insert the posts in category , i used post_category=> array($category_id) but it didn't work .. here is the code

```
$my_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'articles',
        'post_title'    => "test",
        'post_content'    => "blabla",
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array(38),
    );
    
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it after the post creation with:

```
$catid = 38;
wp_set_post_categories($my_post,$catid,false);
```

If you're not sure what's the category ID you can use the category slug:

```
$catid = get_category_by_slug( 'xxx' );
```

The category taxonomy, of course, should already exist in that Custom Post Type.
You can set it in the CPT definition with:

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
```

Comment: $my_post = array(
  'post_type' => 'articles',
  'post_title'    => "test",
  'post_content'    => "blabla",
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'meta_input' => array(
   'post_id' => $post_id,
   
  )
 );
 $catid = (37);
  wp_set_post_categories($my_post,$catid,false);
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
     
i did that but it also didn't work !!

Comment: If it's not working the category taxonomy seems to be not related to the custom post type, so you've to edit the custom post type declaration.